Truenas Scale: Add a second disk to the boot disk
About a year ago I created a TrueNAS Scale instance (TrueNAS-SCALE-23.10.2) but only with 1 SSD for the boot disk. Is it possible to add a second SSD to the boot in RAID?
What would be the best way to do it without damaging the instance?
Hardware: Supermicro X8DT3-F with two Xeon X5650 and one 250 GBs boot SSD

What hardware do you have? For software redundancy solutions boot is often a problem...

@vidarlo sorry, i should add the hardware to the question. I have a Supermicro X8DT3-F with 2 Xeons 5650 and for boot now i have only 1 ssd with 250GBs
